# Forward state with navigateByUrl in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

i want to pass some data, when changing the view with navigateByUrl like

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(url, {state: {hello: "world"}});
```

In the next view i want to simply log the hello attribute like

```
constructor(public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.hello)
  }
```

When I now do it this way, i get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null
    at ProfileContactViewComponent.ngOnInit
```

Am i doing this correctly or is there a better way to pass the data between the views?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

Send :

```
this.router.navigate([url], { state: { hello: 'world' } });
```

Recieve:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.hello); // should log out 'hello'
}
```

For better understanding read the documentation. PFB the link to documentation
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access inside ngOninit, use the location getState function which is available from angular 8+

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
 
export class AComponent
{
  
 
  constructor(private location:Location){
  }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.location.getState());
  }
}
```

Reference Link : https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/